# TextPropTypes is undefined in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm going to make a `Text` component with a custom font.

passed `type` and `style` to `props` and designate `propTypes`.

like this

```js
import {TextPropTypes} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Text.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string,
  style: TextPropTypes.style,
};
```

But if apply it like that, get an error.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, js engine: hermes`

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.TextPropTypes.style')`

```js
console.log('TextPropTypes: ', TextPropTypes)
```

result log is `TextPropTypes: undefined`

it works fine with `ViewPropTypes.style`.

but I want style props of Text component

What should I do?

- react-native `0.63.2`

This is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text as T, TextPropTypes} from 'react-native';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Text = ({children, type, style}) => {
  let textStyle;
  switch (type) {
    case 'r':
      textStyle = styles.regular;
      break;
    case 'b':
      textStyle = styles.bold;
      break;
    case 'l':
      textStyle = styles.light;
      break;
    default:
      textStyle = styles.regular;
      break;
  }

  const passedStyles = Array.isArray(style) ? Object.assign({}, ...style) : style;

  return <T style={[textStyle, {...passedStyles}]}>{children}</T>;
};

export default Text;

Text.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string,
  style: TextPropTypes.style,
};

Text.defaultProps = {
  type: 'r',
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  regular: {
    fontFamily: 'NotoSansCJKkr-Regular',
  },
  bold: {
    fontFamily: 'NotoSansCJKkr-Bold',
  },
  light: {
    fontFamily: 'NotoSansCJKkr-Light',
  },
});
```

Comment: I am not sure but can you try `Text.propTypes.style`.

Comment: @ridvanaltun Thank you for answer. ```Text.propTypes.style``` is not an error but I can't get the codehint I want. [codehint image](https://i.ibb.co/F7F8x8m/2020-09-09-10-35-40.png)

Comment: I am sorry, you imported Text component as T, so you should use `T.propTypes.style` in this case. I was not look into your code but now i see.

Comment: @ridvanaltun Of course. I already used ```T.propTypes.style``` before that. but is same

Comment: Hmm. Object.propTypes usage deprecated when 2017. And TextPropTypes not exist already.

Comment: @ridvanaltun I used ```TextPropTypes```, ```Text.propTypes.style``` and  ```TextStyle``` but nothing works. hmm.. difficult

Answer (score 2):

I guess the new react way is:

```js
import { TextStyle } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

...

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  style: PropTypes.shape(TextStyle),
};
```